# AFNetworking Custom API Manager

Tags: ios, swift, request, afnetworking

For a new app I am designing I want to implement a Request Manager Class (swift) that will handle all the calls to the backend.

Which is the right way to do it? Class Methods or a Singleton and can you please provide me with a pattern or some sample code for me to get started?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use Alamofire instead of AFNetworking. Alamofire was made by the same team as AFNetworking, but it's written in pure Swift.

Singleton pattern is a good choice for APIClient. My approach is to make generic wrapper on Alamofire which handles requests with unified error handling and completions, takes care of authentication headers and stuff.
Next step is to extend generic wrapper (i.e by subclassing) to handle application's domain-specific behavior -> all calls that connects to API goes here.

Big plus of this approach is fact that you can reuse this generic wrapper in another app.

Answer (score 0):

Try Alamofire (AFNetworking for swift)

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http:/www.abc.com" , parameters: ["consumer_key": "Og5pRGI2V"]).responseJSON { response in

        print(response)

  }
```